# Not all language tests are of the same kind

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, semantics

> 1. Not all language tests are of the same kind.
> 2. All language tests are not of the same kind

I think both the sentences mean the same thing though they are syntactically different.

What is the part of speech of *not* in each sentence?

I think not in the sentence 1 is an adjective as it modifies the pronoun *all*

And in the second sentence ,I think, *not* is an adverb as it modifies a verb *are*.

My question is:

Do the two sentences mean exactly the same? or is there any difference?

What part of speech is **not** in the two sentences?

Comment: This has zero to do with parts of speech. Suggest you visit some sites that deal with logic. Not all birds are blue. All birds are not blue.

Comment: @Lambie. I think it is not a matter of logic.We can identify the parts of speech.If nobody answers my question,then I will follow your advice

Comment: I just gave you another example. It most definitely is. Also, your sentences are not really idiomatic. Normally, one would say: **Not all language tests are the same**. And not "of the same kind".

Comment: @Lambie With context, "of the same kind" may make sense.  For instance, one kind of test could be a vocabulary test, while another could be writing composition.  If this sentence is by itself, I agree with you.

Comment: @Lambie.That is not my sentence.It is taken from a reserch paper published by a professor.I think there is nothing wrong with sentence

Comment: In both your examples, "not" is an **adverb** serving as a marker of negation. In 1. it modifies the noun phrase "all language tests", and in 2. it modifies "are".

Comment: @BillJ.I agree with you.I think not  is never an adjective.

Comment: Take careful note of the comments regarding the area of "logic". The English language is *not* completely consistent in how to express matters regarding logic. Knowing the parts of speech will help to understand this sort of sentence. But more important is understanding how English handles true/false propositions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. *[Not all language tests] are of the same kind*.
> 2. *All language tests [are not] of the same kind*.

In both cases, "not" is an **adverb** serving as a marker of negation.

In 1. "not" is a marker of non-verbal negation, where it modifies the noun phrase "all language tests". In 2. "not" is a marker of verbal negation, where it modifies the auxiliary verb "are".

Answer (score -1):

Both sentences mean different things, and that has to do with how logic is expressed through language.

Exchange "language tests" and "kind" with "rectangles" and "squares" to understand the difference more easily.

It is correct to say:

> Not all ***rectangles*** are ***squares***.

Rectangles where all sides are equal are squares, but rectangles without equal sides are not squares, so this statement is correct.

It is not correct to say:

> All **rectangles** are not ***squares***

Some rectangles may be squares as long as the rectangle has all equal sides.

In both examples, "not" is an adverb that modifies "are", but that doesn't matter much in context with understanding logic.

Comment: This answer makes the classic mistake of assuming that language is logical. It isn't, always. Your second example has the same structure as the proverb _All that glisters is not gold_, Personally I have always had difficulty with sentences of this form, but there is no doubt that people sometimes use them to mean the equivalent of your first example.  (It wasn't me that downvoted you, by the way)_